# wxpython GUI app not firing events after actions, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: events, wxpython

I'm working on a wxpython application that has a desktop GUI that allows users to place objects, connect them, move them around, etc.  It has copy/paste and an undo/redo function (to reverse copy/paste and other actions).

If I copy/paste certain objects or perform tasks like connecting them then use undo it works fine.  If I copy/paste other objects the undo event stops firing until I restart my IDE.  (Using Wing).  After the issue starts , pressing CTRL-Z, right clicking undo, nothing works, the event doesn't fire at all so I can't debug a specific action.  Any suggestions on what might be causing this or where to look?

Comment: Do you get the same symptoms if you run your code outside of your IDE i.e. run your code from the command line. `python myapp.py`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, if I "compile" the code (py2exe) and run it as an executable on my development computer and my test virtual machine the same thing happens.  events like "EVT_KEY_DOWN" and "EVT_CHAR_HOOK" don't fire anymore.  I made a test menu with links directly to undo / redo and it fires them correctly even during this error.  The strange thing is it's not like the keyboard stops working, it just stops doing the events.  I can create a text box on my workspace and type into it and otherwise use the program.  This is all inherited code I'm trying to polish.

Comment: This is where the importance of an `mcve` raises its ugly head https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example